# how to stop function in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to stop time() when mouseout event occur?

[jsfiddle link:](http://jsfiddle.net/P4Xy6/122/)

```
`<div id="j" style="height:50px; width:50px; background-color:red;">Hello</div`>


$("#j").mouseenter(function(){
    var count = 3;
    var counterIncrement=1;
    setInterval(timer, 1000); 
    function timer() {
        count = count+counterIncrement;
        if (count == 3  ) {
            counterIncrement = +counterIncrement;
        }
         console.log(count);

    }
});
```

i want to reset timer() function when mouseout even occur again mousein then start which  count =3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the same interval in two DIFFERENT functions (event handles), so that you have to declare a global variable.
At the very beginning of your script, declare:

```
var interval;
```

Assign the interval to this variable in one event handle:

```
interval = setInterval(.....);
```

and clear it when needed in another handle:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

This would be it. Because the variable is globally declared, it will be recognized in both function scopes. It works, because the interval object is passed by reference.

Comment: my setInterval in mouseenter event how can clearInterval in mouseout event? Please provide jsfiddle link!

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it out. Working without jsFiddle ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Capture the return value of `setInterval()`
2. Call `clearInterval(the_value_you_returned_earlier)`